# How to edit a photo for texture

Tags: image

How can I custom crop an image in blender? I need to cut off edges of a photo before I can use it as a texture.

Comment: Check CGmatter tutorial on youtube: https://youtu.be/gz4qV5_zuMo
Or you can use gimp to crop the image

Comment: Without editing the image, you can edit the UV map so that the texture doesn't use the whole picture.

Answer (score 0):

To crop an image in a Shader Editor
you can use [Wrap Vector Math Node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/converter/vector_math.html).

Where X and Y Min vector values represents Left and Bottom sides
and X and Y Max vector values represents Right and Top sides.

[image: Shader Editor Vector Math Wrap node for cropping]